# Database design, can't find suiting structure

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, erd

Lets say i have the following data:

a player can play different minigames. Every minigame can have its own unique data, some data is the same (kills, deaths, time played). Other data is different per minigame (ex. chest opened in minigame1, arrow fired in minigame2, ...)

I am looking to create a good database structure for this.

I thought of having Player in 1 table, Minigame general data (name, ...) in 1 table. but i can't figure out something to contain the unique data per minigame.

The reason i want to do this is because i want to make a statistic page for a player, the statistic page contains all the data from the minigames. I would like to do this without having a big amount of queries to keep performance as good as possible.

Any hints, tips and comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.  The first is the relationship between players and minigames.  This is many to many, unless I miss my guess.

The second is the grouping of distinct minigames into a class, called minigames.  This is like a class/subclass case, except that it's a class/instance case.

Dealing with the second one first, look up "specialization/generalization".  This will give you pointers on how to analyze the games and come up with a conceptual model.  Then look up "class table hierarchy" for how to convert this model into table design.

For the base relation between players and minigames, you are going to need at least one junction table for the many to many relationship between them.  You may want to have this junction table have columns for all the specialized data that relates to one game or another, leaving blank  (NULL) the data that does not pertain.  There are efficiency issues here, but more importantly, there are issues about dealing with three-valued logic when NULLS collide with selection criteria.

If you do decide to go with just one table, look up "single table inheritance".

Your case is a little different from the typical inheritance case, so you are going to have to adapt the techniques to suit your case.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. After i read your post i decided to go with multiple tables, 1 for ever minigame, which contains the data of that minigame and the player. Single table inheritance would leave me with too many NULL values